# How can I style the last of a serie of elements in css with a specific class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the website I'm working on the navigation menu is made by several nested lists, when one element is clicked on the `<li>` element with the page name acquires the `.active` class, if it belongs to a nested list all parent `li` elements above also acquire the `.active` class.
I'd like to be able to style the last `<li>` element with class `.active` since it corresponds to the currently open webpage.
I'm working with Omeka s content management system, which means that I can't use javascript or modify the HTML files, so I'm looking for a solution in pure CSS.

here is the menu structure:
`

```
<ul class="">
<li >
     <a href="">Introduction</a>
</li>
     <li>
          <a href="">level 1</a>
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <a href="">subpage</a>
                   <ul>
                       <li>
                           <a href="">sub-subpage</a>
                           <ul>
                               <li>
                                   <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                               </li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
</ul>
```

`here is when I'm on th page "sub-sub-page":`

```
<ul class="">
<li >
     <a href="">Introduction</a>
</li>
     <li class="active">
          <a href="">level 1</a>
           <ul>
               <li class="active">
                   <a href="">subpage</a>
                   <ul>
                       <li class="active">
                           <a href="">sub-subpage</a>
                           <ul>
                               <li class="active">
                                   <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                               </li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
</ul>
```

`

I've tried to use `li.active:last-of-type` but it only select the last element of type `li`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul *{
    color : #000;
    text-decoration: none
}
ul .active ul li ul li ul li a{
    color : #f00;
    font-weight : bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="">
      <li >
           <a href="">Introduction</a>
      </li>
     <li class="active">
          <a href="">level 1</a>
           <ul>
               <li class="active">
                   <a href="">subpage</a>
                   <ul>
                       <li class="active">
                           <a href="">sub-subpage</a>
                           <ul>
                               <li class="active">
                                   <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                               </li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I should have specified that this is just an example I'm looking for a method that can work even when the lists are nested differently

Comment: Do you want to select a specific item with class or id ?

Comment: I can't use either since the page's HTML is automatically generated and I don't have many options to modify it

Answer (score 0):

It appeared simpler than I first thought:

Given the current structure, from all nested `active` elements you need to select the `li` that only has an `a` element. To make it work in general (other than a *list element*) don't use the `li` element selector at all.

I added two differently nested examples in the snippet along with an `::after` text...

```css
.active > a:only-child        { color: red }
.active > a:only-child::after { content: ' (active)' }
```

```html
<ul class="">
    <li>
        <a href="">Introduction</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="">level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="">subpage</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="">sub-subpage</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<br><br><br>
<ul class="">
    <li>
        <a href="">Introduction</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="">level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="">subpage</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="">sub-subpage</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<br><br><br>
<ul class="">
    <li>
        <a href="">Introduction</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="">level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="">subpage</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Introduction</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="">level 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="">subpage</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="active">
                                        <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">sub-subpage</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">sub-sub-page</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you this works!  but I have an issue when the element selected is not an only child for example let's say I'm on "sub-subpage" instead of "sub-sub-page"